# What is the semantic difference between a listbox and a group with checkboxes?

Tags: html, listbox, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag

The official [ARIA APG Listbox example implementation](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/listbox/examples/listbox-scrollable/) makes extensive use of `aria` attributes.
Which makes sense as they want to show off how to use them.

Their A11y tree for a single option looks like this:

> RootWebArea “Scrollable Listbox Example | APG | WAI | W3C”
>
> - generic
>
>   - main
>
>     - Section
>
>       - generic
>
>         - listbox “Transuranium elements:”
>
>           - option “Berkelium”
>
>             - StaticText “Berkelium”

But usually I would implement the listbox pattern using inputs with `type="checkbox"`
in a group. This would also match their "No ARIA is better than Bad ARIA" [recommendation](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/read-me-first/).
Then the ARIA tree looks like this:

> RootWebArea
>
> - generic
>
>   - group “Choose your monter’s features:”
>
>     - generic
>
>       - checkbox “Scales”

#### My questions now

1. If I want to create an ARIA conforming multi-select what is the preferred approach?
2. What is the semantic difference between a listbox and a group with checkboxes?

Comment: I don’t understand what the relation with Bad ARIA is? For comparison of the tree, only the part starting with `listbox` or `group` respectively is of interest.

Answer (score 1):

As always, the preferred approach depends, in this case also on your user base.

`listbox` allows for a bunch of features to navigate a **big amount of options**, where tabbing through all options would be a pain:

- *arrow key* navigation inside the list
- so you can escape the list with <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- optionally collapsing the box to save visual space
- keyboard shortcuts for beginning and end
- type-ahead to quickly find an option

So, if you have only a relatively short list, the `group` + `checkbox` would be a more lightweight solution.

---

ARIA roles allow to communicate to users what they can expect in terms of the widget’s behaviour. This mainly concerns keyboard navigation.

#### Keyboard Navigation

Here, a simple list of checkboxes, and a list box, differ.

[ARIA states for `listbox`](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#listbox):

> To be keyboard accessible, authors SHOULD manage focus of option descendants for all instances of this role, as described in Managing Focus.

[In Information for Authors](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#managingfocus_authors), this is enforced:

> Authors MUST manage focus on the following container roles: […] `listbox`

This means that inside a list box, **arrow keys** will control focus between single options, <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> might jump to the beginning or the end of the list. The APG list multiple other recommended keyboard shortcuts.

In a simple group of checkboxes, only <kbd>Tab</kbd> would be used.

Managing focus allows for users to bypass repetitive blocks. If the component is not managing focus and requires Tab keys, don’t use the `listbox` role.

#### Collapsible

A second difference is in `aria-expanded`. A list *box* sometimes can be collapsed and expanded, while the `group` role does not allow for this attribute.